# VBA Error 1004 number conversion

Tags: vba, excel

Im a noob when it comes to coding... So I have a fairly simple code that converts this raw data that comes in as text formatting to numbers. The code works till I switch from the raw data sheet to "individual KPI" sheet so when im on the individual kpi sheet and run the macro I get the run-time error.

```
Sub AccountRecon()
    Range("Table_ACCTDATA[[ARP Check Project, prep & formatting spreadsheets Volume]:[Review / Approve GL Reconciliations Minutes]]").Select
    With Selection
        Selection.NumberFormat = "0.0"
        .Value = .Value
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @TimWilliams Oh! My bad (Edited my answer accordingly)

Comment: Don't use `Range` etc without specifiying a worksheet. Otherwise you'll find your code fails unexpectedly when the active sheet isn't the one you planned on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you type

```
With Something
```

It means that `Something` is before every line in the `with .. end with`.

Fixing that mistake would give :

```
Sub AccountRecon()
    Range("Table_ACCTDATA[[ARP Check Project, prep & formatting spreadsheets Volume]:[Review / Approve GL Reconciliations Minutes]]").Select
    With Selection
        .NumberFormat = "0.0" 'Removed "Selection"
        .Value = .Value
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Sifu. But I seem to run into the same problem. I tried to specify the worksheet by using
 
Application.Goto ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("owssvr(1)").Range("Table_ACCTDATA[[ARP Check Project, prep & formatting spreadsheets Volume]:[Review / Approve GL Reconciliations Minutes]]").Select

But i still run into the same issue

Comment: thanks guys!

Sub AccountRecon()
    Sheets("owssvr(1)").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Range("Table_ACCTDATA[[ARP Check Project, prep & formatting spreadsheets Volume]:[Review / Approve GL Reconciliations Minutes]]").Select
    With Selection
        .NumberFormat = "0.0" 'Removed "Selection"
        .Value = .Value
    End With
End Sub